# Good Worker Distribution Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I've a code for checking game implementation. I get a buildlist as an input. Think of the game like AoE. There are 2 types of minerals (eg. gold, wood). I've worker who can either mine the minerals or construct building(or better put, the workers become the building). The buildings or units require certain amount of gold, wood and build time. I would like to know how to redistribute the workers in such a fashion that it is optimised for the best.

I've already thought of few of the cases and solutions, but if there are situations like(in the build list) around 10 workers after building 3 or 4 buildings whom I can use for resources gathering.

I would like to know if there is a good algorithm for the worker distribution to read, and understand better (Not genetic)

Comment: "optimised for the best." Define "best." Do you want one building as fast as possible? As many buildings as possible in some given time? Are there different buildings that require different types and amounts of resources? Do you want the most expensive built with as few workers as possible, regardless of time? When you talk about optimization, you have to decide what exactly you're trying to optimize. You'll have to provide much more detail. Otherwise your question will probably be closed as too broad or unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's an optimization problem. There are entire books on that topic. This might be a good start [https://www.amazon.com/Gentle-Introduction-Optimization-B-Guenin-ebook/dp/B00KL8CHHU/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KL8CHHU)
If you want to learn more about algorithms in general, I recommend
[https://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Robert-Sedgewick-ebook/dp/B004P8J1NA/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004P8J1NA)
and
[https://www.amazon.com/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena-ebook/dp/B00B8139Z8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B8139Z8)